# R / officer package / docx_summary function doesn't exist

Tags: r, docx, officer

I am on R version 3.3.3 using package `officer` 0.1.1

```
library(officer)

docx_summary("doc.docx")
```

Gives this error:

> Error: could not find function "docx_summary"

I tried: `officer::` and `officer:::` but it seems that it is the only missing function.

I tried reinstalling `officer` but the function is always missing.

Comment: `docx_summary()` does not exist in that version of the `officer` package.

Answer (score 1):

`docx_summary` function appears in `officer` 0.1.2 [see news file](https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/blob/87260d0923e71bf632227ba51a06d0e8634e25b2/NEWS#L79).

if you install from cran `install.packages("officer")`, you will get version `0.1.8`. `docx_summary` is in this version.